# Socket.IO: Missed Messages Issue with Undetected Disconnect Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm currently using Socket.IO in our web app to track our users' online presence and update the UI components accordingly. However, I'm encountering a problem where if a user gets disconnected and reconnected too quickly, the disconnect event isn't raised and goes undetected.

This poses an issue as during that brief time, the client may miss incoming messages. Additionally, since I haven't received a disconnect event, I can't ask for any missing messages that may exist.

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this problem and if there's a way to solve it. I have included a basic sample code below that listens to the connect and disconnect Socket.IO client events:

```js
// Sample code to listen to connect and disconnect Socket.IO client event
socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('Connected!');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  console.log('Disconnected!');
});
```